# divide and conquer and recursion

Tags: recursion, divide-and-conquer

I wonder if the technique of divide and conquer always divide a problem into subproblems of same type? By same type, I mean one can implement it using a function with recursion. Can divide and conquer always be implemented by recursion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"Always" is a scary word, but I can't think of a divide-and-conquer situation in which you couldn't use recursion.  It is by definition that divide-and-conquer creates subproblems of the same form as the initial problem - these subproblems are continually broken down until some base case is reached, and the number of divisions correlates with the size of the input.  Recursion is a natural choice for this kind of problem.

See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) for more good information.

Comment: And a recursive problem can always be written using iterative approach and vice versa, so a divide-and-conquer is need not to be written using only recursive approach and a tail recursion is as efficient as a iterative problem solving approach.

Comment: **Function-Recursion will most likely cause StackOverflow error** (yes, the site's name ;-)). So, FIFO looping should be used, where the function's logic will append any new problems (Instead of calling self again).

Answer (score 8):

A Divide-and-conquer algorithm is by definition one that can be solved by recursion.  So the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, yes! [Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is an example of the same. Here is an [animated version](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/dsrkg/cs210/applets/sortingII/mergeSort/mergeSort.html) of the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In divide and conquer algorithmic technique we divide the given bigger problem into smaller sub-problems. These smaller sub-problems must be similar to the bigger problem except that these are smaller in size.

For example, the problem of sorting an array of size N is no different from the problem of sorting an array of size N/2. Except that the latter problem size is smaller than that of former one.

If the smaller sub-problem is not similar to the bigger one, then the divide and conquer technique can not be used to solve the bigger problem. In other words, a given problem can be solved using divide and conquer technique only iff the given bigger problem can be divided into smaller sub problems which are similar to the bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

Examining merge sort algorithm will be enough for this question. After understanding implementation of merge sort algorithm with divide and conquer (also recursion) you will see how difficult it would be making it without recursion.

Actually the most important thing here is the complexity of the algorithm which is expressed with big-oh notation and nlogn for merge sort.

For mergesort exapmle there is another version which is called **bottom-up merge sort**. It is simple and non-recursive version of it.

it is about 10% slower than recursive, top-down mergesort on typical systems. You can refer to following link for more information. It is explained well in 3rd lecture.

https://www.coursera.org/learn/introduction-to-algorithms#

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a programming method where you define a function in terms of itself. The function generally calls itself with slightly modified parameters (in order to converge).

1. Divide the problem into two or more smaller subproblems.
2. Conquer the subproblems by solving them (recursively).
3. Combine the solutions to the subproblems into the solutions for the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes All Divide and Conquer always be implemented using recursion .

A typical Divide and Conquer algorithm solves a problem using following three steps.

1. Divide: Break the given problem into sub-problems of same type.
2. Conquer: Recursively solve these sub-problems
3. Combine: Appropriately combine the answers

[image: Divide And Conquer]

Following are some standard algorithms that are Divide and Conquer algorithms.
1) Binary search,
2) Quick Sort,
3) Merge Sort, 
4) Strassen’s Algorithm

Comment: It's not true that D&C has to "always be implemented using recursion". From your own examples, binary search is something we can easily implement without recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine `P` is a problem with size of `n` and `S` is the solution. In this case, if `P` is large enough to be divided into sub problem, for example `P1`, `P2`, `P3`, `P4`, ... , `Pk`; let say k sub problems and also there would be k solutions for each of k sub problems, like `S1`, `S2`, `S3`, ... , `Sk`; Now if we combine each solutions of sub problem together we can get the S result. In divide and conquer strategy what ever is the main problem all sube problems must be same. For example if `P` is sort then the `P1`, `P2` and `Pn` must be sort too. So this is how it is **recursive** in nature. So, divide and conqure will be recursive.